# fit a table in a middle of an excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, table-of-contents

I have a table in a sheet like this:

[image]

I want to place the table in the middle of page. but the number of column is odd (5) and the number of column in the sheet is even (8). there is 2 cols after table and 1 col before it. so the table is not in the middle and after printing it is not in the middle too.
how can I place the table in the middle of sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your print area to be just the table you want to print ([page layout - print area - set](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Define-or-clear-a-print-area-on-a-worksheet-2e5992fa-f201-41a1-9f39-370ff14deca1)) then in page setup select to center your data both vertically and horizontally.

If you want to see also the empty cells around your table then set the print area to be the seven column wide range and as tall as you need.

Comment: how can I set the print area to be the seven column wide range?

Comment: select the range you want to be printed than click "set print area", I've added link to the solution.